# How do I deal with this warning

Tags: java

My program works but am getting these warning when i compile it.

```
    [javac] warning: [path] bad path element "D:\temp_104\server\lib\xerces-J_1.
4.0.jar": no such file or directory
    [javac] warning: [path] bad path element "D:\temp_104\server\lib\commons-log
ging-1.1.jar": no such file or directory
```

I get that there is a link to the jar somewhere but how can i find it to delete it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Eclipse, there's a "Configure Build Path" menu item, when you Right-click a project and navigate to "Build Path".
If you're not using Eclipse, you just have to find the place where your class path is defined. Whatever command is invoking the javac compiler, it's passing the classpath as argument, find out what it is and where it is and fix it :-)

Comment: An Eclipse-centric solution isn't helpful. Furthermore, the statement that passing the classpath is the issue isn't necessarily accurate. Classpaths can also be included in the manifest of jar files, for instance.